# About MR for the "Import failed: Unexpected epoch change"

Tags: epoch

I saw the epoch issue is solved by this [MR](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11727). However, it didn't work when I tried to test that on my local machine. Do I do something wrong?

The steps are like this

1. Two validators on my local machine to run my rococo-local chain
2. Stop one validator and wait 3 minutes
3. Restart that validator again
4. The epoch issue still happens

Note: polkadot version i 0.9.39-1-298b4aefe1b

Comment: If it is still the case, you could join the MR conversation or open an issue